# Is a Master's degree in Business and Finance from a university in Poland a respected degree in Germany?

Tags: university, germany, ranking, poland

I have been accepted to a Master's program in Business at a top University in Poland. I looked up on Anabin and I do see this university listed there, but this of course is not the whole picture.

I looked up the rankings and although Polish universities fall behind Western universities in the rankings (due largely to the way rankings are calculated), the university I am accepted to is the top ranked university in Poland, depending on which ranking system you use.

This question is more about how Germans feel about it, as it is listed in Anabin so it meets the hard requirements.

Suppose that I wanted to get a job as a business executive like a CFO or CEO, or perhaps some sort of business consultant in Germany, what would employers think of a Polish degree?

I am not from Poland, and I am not Polish; I am American and I considered studying abroad because it is less expensive to live and to study, among other reasons.

I also have the opportunity to go to a German university to get a second Bachelor's degree in Engineering, so I am considering that as well.

I am just trying to make the best decision for the future.

Will I be looked down on for having gone to a Polish university, or will they look and say something like, "Great I see you have a valid degree, this means you met the requirements, now how well do you speak German?"

What do Germans think of Polish degrees, besides it being a valid degree? Do they respect it as perfectly fine (even at large corporations), or do they think it is less than respected? How to Germans actually feel about it?

Comment: Well before one gets hired as a C-level person, one’s accomplishments will far outweigh where you did a degree. Will it make it harder to get your first job? Perhaps…

Comment: So are you saying that a Polish degree would make it harder to get a first job in Germany? Or are you just generalizing?

Comment: It is likely that many potential German employers are not aware of how good (or bad) a Polish university is.

Comment: Do you have first hand experience of this, or how did you arrive at this conclusion? Thank you

Comment: I hire a lot of people in the US. There are many universities and colleges in the US. Many good ones are really only known regionally. Do I have to research them if I haven’t heard of them. Others might not bother.

Comment: I can't give you advice specifically for business and finance, but I think it's worthwhile to point out the following general cultural difference that might be surprising to an American: Generally speaking, university rankings are not a big thing in Germany at all. As a consequence, many Germans will hardly bother whether you got your degree at a "top ranked" or a "low ranked" uni or wherever. Caveat: there will, of course, always be exceptions. For instance, I'm very unsure whether people in consulting (which you mentioned in your post) might tend to have a different view on rankings.

Comment: Also not an answer to your question, but maybe a worthwhile frame challenge: You say you have the option for a Master's program in business and finance and for a Bachelor's program in engineering. Those seem to be quite different paths to go, and each option seems likely to leave you with solid options for a career or further studies. May I suggest that, instead of focussing on uni rankings and prestige and on want somebody in Germany might or might not think about a certain degree in Poland, you could (and maybe should) rather focus on what you think which path you will like more?

Comment: @JochenGlueck I am focusing on what path and I fully would like both paths, but also want a path that will not deny me future opportunities so I don't want to waste my time. Hence the question.